# How to convert string to hex in unpacked BCD format?

Tags: python, hex, bcd

I want to convert the String Entered convert into BCD.

```
a = '2015'
''.join(format(int(c), '04b') for c in str(int(a, 16)))
```

is giving me `'1000001000010011'`. But I want it to read `0010 0000 0001 0011` as in unpacked BCD format. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain what encoding is `'\x20\x15'` to `'2015'` ? That's not hex and not BCD

Comment: @Kasramvd Basically I want to import this number in hex to the microcontroller. The number has been entered with `a = raw_input("Enter no.")`

Comment: @Rockybilly I know it is BCD string but I want to convert it to unpacked BCD. As in digitwise BCD.

Comment: Don't you additionally need a `C` or `D` or `F` for the sign?

Comment: I can't get your question. `int('0011', 2)` is 3, not 5 (your last digit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, as you see, clearer the question make, easier for us to help you.

Here how I managed your problem

```
no = "2015"
bcd = " ".join(["0"*(4 - len(bin(int(number))[2:])) + bin(int(number))[2:] for number in no])

print bcd

# 0010 0000 0001 0101
```

0010 0000 0001 0011 was your output and it is wrong. So your issue is not just the spaces between 4-digit representation. However, to resolve it:

The issue of spaces was because of the

```
''.join()
```

you used. You needed

```
' '.join()
```

instead.

Comment: If you need explanation please mention